# Change value in array controller by typing in table view cell

Tags: objective-c, cappuccino, objective-j

So I have a `CPTableView` with `2 columns`. My `CPTableView` is filled thanks to an `Array Controller` which is bind with the `CPTableView` Columns.

I know how to fill, refill the table view, no problem.

My problem is that I want to change the value of a cell and of course, this value must be changed in the array controller, too.

So I enter my new value by double clicking on the cell, enter it. Ok, but the value isn't changed in the array and it's normal because I didn't tell to the array to do it.

But to change the value in the array, I must be able to get the new value that I wrote in the cell to put in the array.

I can't do this or I don't know how to do this.

I tried the CPTableColumn method : `dataCellForRow` but it doesn't work, the debugger tells me to use `dataViewForRow`. Ok, I use it, but when I get the cell value, it always return : "Text Cell" the default title set for the cell in IB.

So really I don't know how to do what I want.

Comment: You have a UITableView in Cappuccino? Don't you mean a CPTableView?

Comment: Yes, a CPTableView, i wrote TableView and someone edit my post to write UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to tell the array that value is changed. And then reload table.

Do this steps:
1)value changed. changing it in the array
2)reloading table (UItableView has function reloadData). And because you bind array with table reloading will automatically update table

Comment: Of course, i want to do that, but my problem is that i can't change the value in the array because i can't get the new value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `CPTableView` properly bound to a `CPArrayController`, your table cell values should automatically be updated when you edit them and commit the change, through "reverse bindings". Maybe double check that you have bound `CPValueBinding` of each column.

Take a look at this manual test: [`Tests/Manual/ArrayController1`](https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/tree/master/Tests/Manual/ArrayController1) in the Cappuccino repository. If I don't remember wrong it implements this.

If that fails you can always do it by hand using this table view delegate method:

`tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:`

Try to add something like this to your table delegate (untested):

```
- (void)tableView:(CPTableView)tableView setObjectValue:(id)aValue forTableColumn:(CPTableColumn)tableColumn row:(int)aRow
{   
    var name = [tableColumn identifier];

    CPLog.info("Row %d of table column %@ changed to %@.", aRow, name, aValue);
    // ... change actual model here.
}
```

Take a look at [`Tests/Manual/TableTest/Editing`](https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/tree/master/Tests/Manual/TableTest/Editing) in the Cappuccino repository for an example of this.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will check this and i'll tell you if i succeed.

Comment: I saw that in the example, columns and bindings are created programmatically. I bound my columns with my CPArrayController in IB and it works fine. I don't know why with IB bindings, the CPArrayController isn't aware that a cell value changed..

Comment: Should work fine with IB bindings too. If you are confident you've made the bindings properly but they're still not working, please create a minimal test case and submit a bug report here: https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/issues

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it works, I was not on the good way..

To check if my cell value has changed, i looked for it in the 'CPArray' which contains the data. But this array isn't bind to my 'CPTableView', it's the 'CPArrayController' which is bound. So i checked in this one and i saw that the cell value has modified correctly !

Thank you for your time.